# JOOQ forced types configuration for specific table in DB

Tags: jooq

Any idea how to make XML configuration of forcedTypes for only specific table? Having "table1" and "table2" both with column "date" but I need to convert only the one from "table1".

Answer (score 2):

You just have to qualify the `<forcedType>`:

```
<forcedType>
  ..
  <inputExpression>TABLE\.COLUMN</inputExpression>
</forcedType>
```

Note that prior to jOOQ 3.12, you had to *fully* qualify the expression, so your regex needed to match the schema as well:

```
<forcedType>
  ..
  <expression>(.*?\.)?TABLE\.COLUMN</expression>
</forcedType>
```